# Should I serialize an array before caching with APC?

Tags: php, apc

I am just getting started with APC to cache data and was wondering if I should store the data as an array or serialize the array before storing it?

The goal is to use the least amount of resources possible for both inserting and retrieving the data for display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. Because APC is memory storage, you can even store object without serialize.